# Keras cross-validation overfitting: is my model carrying over information across different folds?

Tags: python, keras

I would like to ensure that my code for running a cross-validation of a Keras model is correct. Currently I suspect that it is wrong, because the results appear to be over-fitting.

My code structure generally looks like as follows:

```
def get_model():
    ....
    #code to create a Keras Neural network model using the functional API

kfold = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=5, shuffle=True, random_state=42)
splits = list(enumerate(kfold.split(X, y))) #X is the train feature matrix, y the target
model= get_model() #LINE A
model.compile(...) #LINE B

for k in range(0, len(splits)): #LINE C
   split = splits[k]
   X_split_train = ... #slice X into corresponding training parts
   X_split_test
   y_split_train = ... #slice y into corresponding parts
   model.fit(X_split_train, y_split_train, ...)
   prediction_prob = model.predict(X_split_test)
   #... code for evaluating the result for this fold
```

And I suspect my code is wrong. Specifically, line A and B should be within the loop, line C.

Reasons for my suspicion:

1. Looking at the training log generated for all epochs, there seems to be continuation of model performance over different folds. Say For the first fold the model obtains an accuracy of 75%. In the second fold, it starts reporting an accuracy 75.x% upwards
2. the model seems to be overfitting as it soon outputs training accuracy of 1.0
3. for some rare classes that have only 1 instance in the dataset, in some cases the model even reported 100% F1 for those classes and this doesn't make sense.

All these seem to suggest that the model parameters and learned class distribution seem to be carried forward between folds. And the only way to fix this I suppose, is to re-create the model in every fold. Is this correct?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this code is not doing cross-validation correctly, for each fold you train a new model from scratch, here you are reusing the model from the previous fold, which is incorrect.

I would do it like this:

```
for k in range(0, len(splits)): #LINE C
   model= get_model() #LINE A
   model.compile(...) #LINE B

   split = splits[k]
   X_split_train = ... #slice X into corresponding training parts
   X_split_test
   y_split_train = ... #slice y into corresponding parts
   model.fit(X_split_train, y_split_train, ...)
   prediction_prob = model.predict(X_split_test)

   del model
```